# Valid characters in "From:" display name for emails

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using PEAR Mail to send emails, and I found that if the "From:" field is something like `From: Dragoş <email@example.com>`, PEAR returns an error:

`Validation failed for: Dragoş <email@example.com>`

But, if I remove the `ş`, PEAR returns true and sends email.

I tried to search on Google and StackOverflow for valid characters, but seems I have no luck here.
Does anyone know **what are the valid characters for the display name in From field?**

Also, is there any way to "encode" these chars to be allowed on this field? I use PHP.

Thank you!
Nuno

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MIME you have to use only ASCII encoded characters.

In order to pass non-ASCII chars, you have to use [Word encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word).

Copied from the linked article:

> For example,
>
> Subject:
>   =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1Hola,_se=F1or!?=
>
> is interpreted as "Subject: ¡Hola,
>   señor!".

The same can be applied to the "name" part (not the email) of the "From" and "To" MIME fields.

Comment: Thank you! That worked well! I thought I could only use this for Subject. I have just tested on From and worked well so far :)

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, consult [the standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt).  What you're after is the `display-name` token, which is described on page 14.